# Are artificial intelligence learnings or trainings transferable from one agent to the other?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, training, intelligent-agent

One disadvantage or weakness of Artificial Intelligence today the slow nature of learning or training success. For instance, an AI agent might require a 100,000 samples or more to reach an appreciable level of performance with a specific task. But this is unlike humans who are able to learn very quickly with a minimum number of samples. Humans are also able to teach one another, or in other words, transfer knowledge acquired.

My question is this: are Artificial Intelligence learnings or trainings transferable from one agent to the other? If yes, how? If no, why?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest case is copying the software. That is instant duplication of the learnings. In a similar, but less trivial way you can adjust pretrained neural network classifiers to new datasets by simply re-initializing the last layer.

It gets more interesting when you have multiple agents and you want to combine their knowledge. This can be done with many techniques; the simplest is averaging the weights of identical neural network architectures. One example of this *combined learning* happened is [Google Has a Room Full of Robot Arms Learning Hand-Eye Coordination](https://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/robots/a20190/google-room-full-of-robot-arms/). The relevant paper is [Learning Hand-Eye Coordination for Robotic Grasping with Deep Learning and Large-Scale Data Collection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02199.pdf).

The most complicated case, where you want to transfer just the gist and prevent forgetting is -- up to my knowledge, and I'm relatively certain it's outdated in that area -- unsolved. The problem is **post-hoc explanations**. Humans decide to do something, observe the outcome and then explain why they did something / why it was good to do it. So we automatically generate hypotheses about the world. And sometimes we are able to formulate them in a way that others can understand them. That is not possible with current learning machines. We don't know yet how to abstract automatically from arbitrary problems.

Comment: I am confident transfer of learnings from one agent to the other will be a surer route to achieving artificial general intelligence.